# Correlated GBM and OU processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to model two different stochastic processes, such that:

$X_t , V_t$ are correlated with coefficient $\rho$. Where:

$\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=\mu_1dt+\sigma_1 dW_{1,t}$ and $dV_t=\theta(\mu_2-V_t)dt+\sigma_2 dW_{2,t}$.

Is there any source(book or paper) to address this problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the purpose of the Model is? Is it to drive some analytical formula, simulate something, or study the behaviour of some functions of these variables?

Comment: what correlation do you want? do you want the correlation of returns? of log normal returns? of the brownian driving processes?

Comment: My omission. Between the Brownian Motion $dW_{2,t} $ and $dW_{1,t}$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for? if you want correlation $\rho$ between two Brownian motions, it's modeled as $$
W_t^2 = \rho W_t^1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_t, 
$$